# Having issue with MySQL INNER JOIN query having sub-query in it

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have two tables, category and images. Here, Category.ID == Images.Category

**Category**

```
-----------------------
| ID | parent | name  |
-----------------------
| 1  | 1      | foo   |
| 2  | 1      | bar   |
| 3  | 2      | lorem |
-----------------------
```

**Images**

```
--------------------------------------
| ID  | category    | url            |
--------------------------------------
| 1   | 1           | foo.jpg        |
| 2   | 2           | bar.jpg        |
| 3   | 1           | foo2.jpg       |
--------------------------------------
```

**I tried MySQL Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM `category`
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MAX(ID) , url, category FROM `images` GROUP BY `category`)
AS a ON category.ID = a.category
WHERE `parent` = '1'
```

**Which Results in**

```
-------------------------------------------
| ID | parent | name  | url     | max(ID) |
-------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1      | foo   | foo.jpg | 3       |
| 2  | 1      | bar   | bar.jpg | 2       |
-------------------------------------------
```

**The Problem is**

I want url of last added row in here, but as in first row, Instead of url = foo2.jpg and max(ID) = 3, it results in foo.jpg. I can't figure out the problem in query.

I use max(ID) for getting last row, which gives correct last row for max(ID) but not appropriate url column.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM `category`   AS c
INNER JOIN images AS i ON i.category = c.id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  category, MAX(ID) AS MAXId
    FROM `images` 
    GROUP BY `category`
)AS a  ON i.category = a.category
      AND i.ID       = a.MaxID
WHERE c.`parent` = '1';
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b94b7/3)

The problem is that, you were `GROUP BY category` inside the subquery and select `MAX(ID) , url, category` which were not included in an aggregate function nor in the `GROUP BY` clause, so MySQL picks up an arbitrary value for these columns. Thats why you were getting in consistent results.

To solve this, `JOIN` the two tables `category` and `images` normally, then add an extra join between the table `images` and a subquery which compute the `MAX(id)` with `GROUP BY category` for the same table `images`. Then join this subquery with the table `images` on the join condition that the max `id` = to the original `id`.

This will give you only those image details for the last `id`.

Comment: @user1995997 - You're welcome any time. See my edit for more info about this issue.

Comment: Now I understood very well. Thanks for such great response.

Answer (score 1):

In a Shorter way

```
SELECT c.id,c.parent,c.name, MAX(c.ID) , url, category
    FROM `category` c
    INNER JOIN Images i on c.id=i.id and 
     c.id=(select max(id) from category)
```

I think this query will work for you..tested with sql fiddle...with this link.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fe63/36

let me know if solved

Comment: Connection between both table is Category.ID == Images.Category. Yes this pattern will works too, thanks for the answer.